# Convention on Cauchy's two line notation for permutations

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation, permutations

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$. A permutation $\sigma\in S_n$ is denoted in Cauchy's two line notation as follow:
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & \cdots & n \\ \sigma(1) & \sigma(2) & \cdots & \sigma(n)
\end{pmatrix}
My question is how do we normally interpret $\sigma(i)$, for all $1\leq i\leq n$? I have found (at least) two different ways to interpret it:

1. $\sigma(i)$ is the letter in the $i$th position (after the permutation is applied);
2. $\sigma(i)$ is the position of the letter $i$ (after the permutation is applied).

In general these two interpretations give rise to different permutations. For example suppose $123$ is being rearranged into, says, $231$. Then interpretation 1 gives 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 2 & 3 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
but interpretation 2 gives 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 3 & 1 & 2
\end{pmatrix}
My question will be that which convention do mathematicians usually follow?

Thanks in advance for clearing my doubt.

Comment: If you write $\sigma(i)$ then this will usually mean that you are considering $\sigma$ to be a function, and therefore the first interpretation is the correct one.

Comment: Ok thanks. But isn't the second interpretation also satisfies the criteria of being a (valid) function? namely (1) the letter $i$ must be at some position (the image of an element must be in the codomain), and (2) the letter $i$ can at most occupy only one position (any element must have at most one image).

Comment: But that is not how one considers a permutation to be a function (in fact, a permutation is by definition a bijective function, so the notation $\sigma(i)$ is in this context completely unambiguous).

Comment: Yeah I know that it is a bijection. I think interpretation 2 also satisfies the bijectivity (1) one-to-one: if the letters $i$ and $j$ occupy the same position, then it must be $i=j$; (2) onto: every position must be occupied by some letter. That's why I am curious about the usual convention people stick to. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Definitely the first. Think about what happens when the set being permuted does not have a 'natural' ordering (e.g. {apple,orange,banana}): the first way of writing makes immediate sense, but for the second you need to arbitrarily pick an order in which to enumerate the elements.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I encounter interpretation 2 through the following: Some book first write down the letter 123, then draw an arrow pointing from the top of letter 1 to the top of letter 3, then draw an arrow pointing from the bottom of letter 3 to the bottom of letter 2 and finally an arrow from the bottom of letter 2 to the bottom of letter 1. If we read this by following the arrow, then interpretation 2 makes natural sense (at least to me), and it also works for your fruits example, perhaps except that, as you have said, I have presumed the ordering (apple, orange, banana). Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of your interpretations are very clear, although interpretation 1 gives you the correct result if I understand you correctly.

A permutation acts on a set; thinking of the "position" of a letter after applying to permutation (to what?) does not make a lot of sense.  You seem to be thinking of having a string $123\ldots n$, where each letter has a distinct position, then you are applying the permutation to this string letter-by-letter to obtain a new string, where you can talk about the "positions".  This is a complicated viewpoint, and I don't know that it is especially useful.

Your first interpretation is closest to correct; you should modify it to say "$\sigma(i)$ is the letter obtained by applying the permutation to the letter $i$". Then if $123$ is arranged to $231$, you see that $\sigma:1 \to 2$, $\sigma:2 \to 3$, $\sigma:3 \to 1$. This gives you 
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ \sigma(1) & \sigma(2) & \sigma(3)\end{pmatrix} = 
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 & 3\\ 2 & 3 & 1\end{pmatrix}.$$

Notice the convenience of this notation; it is very easy to look up the image of any letter under your permutation.

Comment: Note that interpretation (2) is $\sigma^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2):

Interpretation 1 is correct. If we are given a string ( not just a set ) we want to express permutations of the objects in some useful manner. That's what the Cauchy notation does.

" This is a complicated viewpoint, and I don't know that it is especially useful". As a physicist I assure you, it's the ONLY useful thing about permutation groups. I've never seen permutation groups in physics used any other way.

Comment: It should be noted that ,in general, sets are unordered. Thus the set {1,2,3} is the same as {2,1,3}, or for that matter {2,2,1,3,3,3}. So to say permutation groups act on sets is meaningless. Only when they act upon strings can one permutation be concretely distinguished  from another.